# Singularly cast an array of strings to custom enum type in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, casting

I am trying to cast a list of strings to a list of custom enum types. The effect I am looking for can be achieved with this:

```
select * from table_1 where column_a in (cast('ENUM1' AS custom_enum), cast('ENUM2' AS custom_enum))
```

But since I am attempting this to bypass some JPA/hibernate issues I am having with annotated filters on sql enum types, I need to dynamically add the enum strings to the list. So I am trying to figure out how to cast a whole list of strings to a list of enum_types. I'm guessing something like this:

```
select * from table_1 where column_a in (cast({'ENUM1', 'ENUM2'} AS custom_enum[]))
```

But not much I have tried gives me any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `= ANY` instead of `IN`. The array literal should be enclosed in quotes:

```
select * 
from table_1 
where column_a = any (cast('{ENUM1, ENUM2}' as custom_enum[]))
```

or cast the column to `text`:

```
select * 
from table_1 
where column_a::text in ('ENUM1', 'ENUM2')
```

Comment: That's it! Looks like hibernate filtering doesn't like it unfortunately but thank you.